# Painting multiple textures at once

Tags: texture-painting

I'm curious whether it's possible or not to clone paint on multiple texture slots at once? I want my clone painting to affect all the maps I have on an object. If that's not possible is it possible to copy clone strokes to the other maps somehow?

Thanks,
Mitchell

Answer (score 1):

if u use the same picture on both materials its supposed to work like this:[image]

and dont forget to set the uvs correctly :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you elaborate on your answer please? We prefer answers that are more than a comment on their own.

Comment: i wanted to comment but i dont have 50 reputation, so i answered

Comment: It is very easy to earn more rep here. You can edit some posts, you get 2 points for each approved edit, and you are 3 upvotes away from 50. Write a solid answer or ask a great question :)

Comment: i tried on a cube and it worked, heres a screenshot!

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to clone all texture images at once. Paint works on a single source to target, so cloning from one part of your Diffuse map will only affect that Diffuse map, not the Normal map that is also part of the material texture slots.